# ExtJS tree loading (change proxy url)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have **Ext.tree.Panel** and I use **Ext.data.TreeStore** for my tree.

```
var storeTree = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    expanded: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/tree'
    },
    root: {
        text: 'Ext JS',
        id: 'src',
        expanded: true
    },
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
});
```

**Everything works!**

But I need now something like that: at the first time, when I open page, when my tree will be loaded, I need to get JSON Tree from the another location (For example ,  first time I want to get JSON from /tree1 and then , when I expand my tree, to get from /generalTree);

In the other words, At the first time, I want to load tree from anotther JSON. I don't know now. Or may I send parameter , to the server, which will tell it, that it is first time of using tree (Hey, server, tree is expanded automatically by me, not from user clicking)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can call the [load](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-load) method on the store and use another url for the request or add parameters:

```
// different URL
storeTree.load({
    url: '/treeinit'
});

// parameters
storeTree.load({
    params: {
        init: true
    }
});
```

Comment: No, No. After first load, I don't want to load another JSON together. it gets 2 responses. I deed only one response.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you're trying to say here. Please be more specific of what you're actually trying to achieve. Just for clarification, I was suggesting two **alternative** approaches, of course you won't need both of them at the same time.

Comment: they create two requests. Firts request is created by your code (one of them), and another is created by the treestore proxy

Comment: The store should not do a request automatically, if it is configured correctly. Do not use autoLoad on the store and try setting expanded to `false` on your root node.

Comment: after some configuration yes. then you need also children:[] in root:{}

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Ext.tree.Panel

```
listeners : {

        beforeload: function ( th, records, successful, operation, eOpts ){
          console.log("load");
          storeTree.getProxy().extraParams.().extraParams.changableParam  = 'second';
          storeTree.getProxy().url = '/another url';
        }

}
```